# Entry point level for buying stocks

Tags: stocks, investing

With the Brexit in full force this Friday, many US indexes fell anywhere from 3-5%. Is Monday a good entry point for a buyer's mind or will the bull continue for the next few weeks?

Comment: Nobody can really answer this question accurately because nobody knows how the markets will perform on Monday or what events may transpire over the weekend.  The markets had a very volatile day today and I purchased the "inverse VIX" near the close today in hope that the volatility would subside, but this is purely a gamble and I have no idea how things will pan out.  Buying anything on Monday may prove to be a good move or a bad move.

Comment: good input! And I know nobody really knows if it will continue to be bull/bear, I was just wanting to know others opinions :P

Comment: Certainty: if you try this trading idea, you will lose money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but the answer is that nobody knows for sure.

Read all the conflicting opinions about what might happen in the future, make your best guess, make an estimate of how confident you are in the correctness of that guess, and decide how much you are ready to bet on that belief.

If you aren't convinced, the right thing to do may be nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you think it's a good entry point, it's a good entry point.

Comment: :D I hope not! I could see it going down a little more at beginning of week but then showing green in the later portion

Comment: @TannerTriggs lol, then it's a bad entry point!

Comment: maybe so maybe not!